# Bootstrap "button" without btn class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button

Is it possible to have this kind of design but without btn class ?

I need to display this to inform user of status but i don't want the "mousover" changhing style, juste information.

The code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
 <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-ok active">
  <input type="radio" name="relevance" value="1" checked="checked"/>
  O
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-ko ">
  <input type="radio" name="relevance" value="0"/>
  N
 </label>
 <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-dunno ">
  <input type="radio" name="relevance" value="-1"/>
  ?
 </label>
</div>
```

My result (with custom class):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6CT8IKYEHhydUFCVVpvNE9SWDg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add "disabled" class to buttons and correct the opacity.

```
.foo .btn.disabled {opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100);-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to override the `:hover` and `:active` selectors for the `.btn` and `.btn-default` class in CSS.

Bootstrap's CSS changes the background color on `:hover` and add an inner shadow on top on `:active`.

Comment: I tried this but it's do not affect the "click" design.

Comment: You should override the `:active` selector too to achieve that. I edit.